# <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> file not found in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, facebook

I am trying to create a Custom Module for my React Native app, and I've followed [the guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#create-custom-native-module-files) However, when I create the header file and import **<React/RCTBridgeModule.h> ** I am getting error as **'React/RCTBridgeModule.h'** file not found. I Googled and tried various solution from SO, however, none of them works.

One thing I've noticed is that I am able to import the <React/{any-header-file.h}> file in the AppDelegate.mm, but when I try it in my **Custom Module** I can't get the completition suggestions too. Any help is really appreciated.

**Info:**
I am using react-native 0.72.7.
and Xcode 15.

**Solutions I tried:**

1. Clean Pods and Cache.
2. Re-installed node modules.
3. Configured Header Search Paths.
4. Edits Schemes.

**Expected behaviour**
Will able to import RCTBridgeModule header file.